# Should we allow repeated/duplicated information across multiple tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, tag-wiki

I was looking at the [python](/questions/tagged/python) and the [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tags and noticed that they have sections of exact same text. To me, this doesn't make much sense because if the text in the main tag wiki gets changed, the text in the sub-wiki becomes inaccurate. In fact, this has already occurred since the *3.x* tag wiki says the current stables versions are `2.7.2 and 3.2.2`, while the main tag wiki states they are `2.7.3 and 3.2.3`.

The [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) tag has the exact same problem.

I've gone ahead and suggested edits to just reference the main [python tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) instead. Is there any better way to reference the same information on multiple tag wikis, or should version-specific tag wikis stick to specific information related to that version only, and just link to the overall information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or should version-specific tag wikis stick to specific information related to that version only, and just link to the overall information?

If there is information specific to that version, that information should be shown on the version-specific-tag wiki, otherwise the tag wiki should point to the generic information given in the generic-tag wiki.

The information specific for the version could be:

- The classes or modules introduced with the specific version
- Examples of code that worked with the previous version and that needs to be changed for the specific version